# JQuery UI Tabs - loading tab with AJAX is 'breaking' a plugin

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I have page that creates a table: http://gupii.co.uk/rap/weekTable.php and I'm using a plugin to add a filter functionality: _http://gupii.co.uk/rap/js/mylibs/tablefilter.js

In weekTable.php:

```
var theTable = $('#weekTable')
$("#filter").keyup(function() {
$.uiTableFilter( theTable, this.value );
})
```

This works fine when your directly on the weekTable page, but when I load the page into a JQueryUI tab and try and use the filter I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
 } has no method 'uiTableFilter'
```

Whats going on here, why am I getting this error?

The page I'm trying to load into is _http://gupii.co.uk/rap/guilda.php (tab:This Week) if it helps

(apologies for posting more links than I should but I thought it would be helpful in diagnosing the problem)

Comment: problem solved! While double checking which version of JQuery I was loading I realised I'd loaded it on both pages. Removing one of the calls solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#filter").live("keyup", function() {
    ...
```

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you loading?